# struggling to add a follow up function with my speech recognition app c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

so for example i say "play next song" and my app does so, and i want a function that starts listening again for 3 seconds only for the words "one more" so it can skip one more time then listen again for 3 seconds, if the 3 seconds pass i want the loop statement to close.

heres what i've tried":

```
        private async void Default_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
         string speech = e.Result.Text;
         switch (speech)
         {
             case "play next":
                    Speak.SpeakAsync("playing next");
                    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero); //this line is just my "play next" function.
                    _next_song.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); //this line enables a different voice recognition function.
                    break;
         }



//void to continue next song again
        private async void _next_song_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsyncStop(); //this is my main recognizer that contains all the commands
            while (true)
            {
                if (speech == "one more")
                {
                    Speak.SpeakAsync("sure");
                    keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
                    return;

                }
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                break;
            }
            _next_song.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }
```

the thing is, my code works, just not the way i want it to, when i say "play next" it plays next song and waits for me to say "one more" to skip one more time and starts listening again, it just doesn't break the chain when 3 seconds pass, only if it hears something else, then 3 seconds later, it goes back to the main _recognizer recognition function.

anyway i could achieve a followup command without using a different SpeechRecognition Module ?
would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i propose a solution if i have understood your problem, so i think you dont need to use two recognizers: i just use an int to trap the phase and thread to do the loop..

```
    //directives needed for thread
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    //--------------------------
    public int phase;
    public bool onemore;
    public bool running;
    private Thread thread;

    public readonly AutoResetEvent _signalGo = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    //To put in the constructor of the class
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loop));

    private void speechRecognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        lblDemo.Content = speech;
        switch (speech)
        {
            case "play next":
                if (phase != 0) return;
                if (!running)
                    thread.Start();
                else
                    _signalGo.Set();

                Speak.SpeakAsync("playing next");
                keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
                break;
            case "one more":
                if (phase != 1) return;
                onemore = true;
                Speak.SpeakAsync("sure");

                break;
        }
    }

    public async void loop()
    {
        running = true;
        while (running)
        {
            phase = 1;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            //if sou say onemore=true, enter in loop
            while(onemore)
            {
                    onemore = false;

                //if you say again onemore before end of 3s, so reloop
                keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENTEDKEY, IntPtr.Zero);
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            } 

            phase = 0;

            if (!running) break;
            _signalGo.WaitOne();//wait _signalGo.set() to continue
            if (!running) break;
        }
    }
```

---

```
        //Dont forget to dispose the resources at the end of program
       // for eaxmple in the destructor
       // if your class is named toto
       //destructor is ~toto
  public class toto
  {
       //constructor
       public toto()
       {
       }

       //destructor
       ~toto()
       {
         _signalGo.Set();
         running = false;

         _signalGo.Dispose();
         speechRecognizer.Dispose();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213997/discussion-on-answer-by-frenchy-struggling-to-add-a-follow-up-function-with-my-s).